# How can I get longitude and latitude of map where user has click on map

Tags: android, google-maps

I want to get the `latitude` and `longitude` where user has click on the map, in button click listener. But when I do it. Then it gets latitude and longitude of current location. But I want the `longitude` and `latitude` of location where the user has `Longclick` on the map.

**My button click listener is this:**

```
saveButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            AudioManager audioManager = (AudioManager)getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
            LocationManager manager = (LocationManager)getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
            Location location = manager.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
            double longi = location.getLongitude();
            double lati  = location.getLatitude();
            int mode = audioManager.getRingerMode();
            int val = audioManager.getStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
            String _name = locationName.getText().toString();

            if (_name.equals("")){
                locationName.setError("Enter a Name");
            }
            else {
                database.insertEntry(_name, lati, longi, mode, val);
                finish();
            }


        }
    });
```

Comment: Have you tried `saveButton.setOnLongClickListener(new View.OnLongClickListener() {});` ?

Comment: yes i have tried it, but how can i get that location's latitude and longitude.  and pass these to saveButton click listener for saving in database

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `setOnMapClickListener` as follows:

```
googleMap.setOnMapClickListener(new OnMapClickListener() {
   @Override
   public void onMapClick(LatLng latLng) {
                   //here you are getting latlong on map click 
   }
}
```

Where `googleMap` is your `GoogleMap` class object

Comment: yes i tried it but i want to pass the latitude and longitude of this location where user has click on the map, in my saveButton click listener

Comment: Save the lat, lng in variables and get it in your button click.

Answer (score 1):

You should `implements OnMapClickListener` for that and implement `onMapClick(..)`

```
@Override
public void onMapClick(LatLng point) {
//Get point as Location
}
```

Refer [Demo tutorial](http://android-er.blogspot.in/2013/01/google-maps-android-api-v2-example.html)

Answer (score 0):

What you need to do is Just make the global variable as `location` and set the latitude and longitude in location listener method of map activity only if you implemented `OnMyLocationChangeListener` like this

```
Location location = null;

    @Override
    public void onMyLocationChange(Location lastKnownLocation) {
        location  = lastKnownLocation
    }
```

Then

```
saveButton.setOnLongClickListener(new View.OnLongClickListener() {
 @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
//Get the location variable which is defined earlier.
}
});
```